# Understand AngularJS $rootScope functionality

Tags: angularjs

I am using Angular and AngularUI to build an application and I am implementing some route protection via the `$stateChangeStart` event.  When my application first starts up I want to initialize a `$rootScope.currentChevron` to be the first element in a list of chevrons.  From then on, another controller will modify this `currentChevron` object within it's own scope, however it appears that the changes are not persisting back to the `$rootScope`. Here is my code

**Angular Run**

```
app.run(function ($rootScope) {
        $rootScope.Chevrons = [
            {
                'name': 'Start',
                'state': 'new.start',
                'active': true,
                'next': 'review-accounts'
            },
            {
                'name': 'Review Accounts',
                'state': 'new.review-accounts',
                'active': false,
                'next': 'settings'
            },
            {
                'name': 'Backup Settings',
                'state': 'new.settings',
                'active': false,
                'next': 'final-review'
            },
            {
                'name': 'Final Review',
                'state': 'new.final-review',
                'active': false,
                'next': null
            }
        ];
        $rootScope.currentChevron = $rootScope.Chevrons[0];


        $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart',
            function (event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {
                var e = event;
                // This is where we need to do route protection

                // First lets find what Chevron we are currently on
                var indexOfChev = $rootScope.Chevrons.indexOf($rootScope.currentChevron);
            });
    });
```

**Inside Controller**

```
$scope.navigate = function (chevron, ind) {
            $state.go(chevron.state);

            $scope.step.active = false;
            chevron.active = true;
            $scope.step = chevron;
            $scope.currentChevron = $scope.step;
            $scope.Index = ind;

        }
```

The problem is after `navigate` is executed, the `$rootScope.currentChevron` is not updated to be the new one. Is there a way to get this functionality to work?

Comment: I think you need to assign $rootScope.currentChevron in your $scope.navigate function.

Comment: so using `$scope.currentChevron` isn't like an alias to `$rootScope.currentChevron`? I just want to modify the global `$rootScope.currentChevron`

Comment: ok, so the strange thing is I also have a `$rootScope.Chevrons` array of chevron object that IS getting updated correctly from within the controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

inject $rootScope into the controller, then instead of

`$scope.currentChevron = $scope.step;`

do

`$rootScope.currentChevron = $scope.step;`

Comment: That worked! Is it not bad to directly modify $rootScope from the controller though?

Comment: Generally it's advised not to use $rootScope. Angular suggests that you instead create a `service` for functionalities that need to be shared among come controllers